# IPrincipal or Membership to retrieve username

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference when retrieving username for the view?

```
<%= Page.User.Identity.Name %>
```

or

```
<%= Membership.GetUser().UserName %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx), `GetUser` *gets the information from the data source and updates the last-activity date/time stamp for the current logged-on membership user.*

`Page.User.Identity.Name` does not do that. It reads information that is readily available in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Page.User.Identity.Name give the identity of the currently logged user. Membership.GetUser() allow you to get the information about the user.

BTW, calling getUser() without parameter is the same as

```
Membership.GetUser(Page.User.Identity.Name)
```

So, if you just need the userName, use Page.User.Identity.Username and use Membership.GetUser() to get more informations about the user, like the email, or to perform action on the user like changing his password.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

Page.User.Identity gets populated when the page goes through the pipeline.

Membership.GetUser().UserName goes and gets the information again, from the database, Active Directory or wherever else the provider supports, causing a second lookup.

It's unlikely to change, so I'd use Page.User.Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Note it's quite possible to have `User.Identity.Name` to reference a user that doesn't even exist in the membership database. This is Forms Authentication and a general abstraction of the concept of a `User` which does not necessarily even exist in the membership database.

If you delete the current user from the membership database then `User.Identity.Name` will retain its original value.